# Rails - Vanity urls for form submits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have made a vanity url for a user signup page:

```
match 'signup' =>'users#new'
```

When there are errors and the controller action 'create' shows the form again, the url is `users/create`.
Can I match `signup` to the create action as well? Also, the create action is posted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add :via

```
match 'signup' =>'users#new', :via => :get
match 'signup' =>'users#create', :via => :post
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works and is a little bit shorter:

```
get 'signup' =>'users#new'
post 'signup' =>'users#create'
```